# Do HUD settlement statements get sent to the federal government?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

One of the forms I see prepared for a real estate transaction I am doing is a "HUD Settlement Statement". I am paying cash, but the form refers to me as a "borrower". The top of the form looks like this:

[image]

The form has all kinds of details about how much I am paying for the property. Is this information being provided to the federal government?